# Value of the cell moves to the left after editing in the userform

Tags: excel, vba, format, cell, userform

I have been facing a strange issue lately. So, the user has the ability to change value of the cell from the userform window, however, after apply changes somehow the values go from the right to the left (only ones with decimals) and that creates a problem when the data is read by another software (Matlab) it can not be read. I have tried to reformat it as number or general to see what happens but nothing. The only thing that changes it back to the right is (find & Replace "," with ","). Anyone knows why this happens? Any solutions ? (see picture for demonstration)

[image]

[image]

Comment: My guess is that the ones formatted to the left are strings, and the ones to the right are numbers, right? It's odd that replacing the comma turns it back into a number, while formatting as a number does not. How does the useform aplly the value? Maybe you can change that.

Comment: Maybe look in the code for the user form. As I understand it the edit box treats everything as a string. So when the number goes initially from the sheet to the form it is converted into a string. Hence when it is written back, the sheet thinks it’s a string. In the code underlying the form you need to intervene and turn the string back to a number (eg using CDbl() ). If you enter a value (or change) a number directly on the sheet, Excel will try and be ‘helpful’ and convert things that look like numbers into numbers (it does the same with dates).

Comment: @DS_London Worked magically. Thank you for this tip.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe look in the code for the user form. As I understand it the edit box treats everything as a string. So when the number goes initially from the sheet to the form it is converted into a string. Hence when it is written back, the sheet thinks it’s a string. In the code underlying the form you need to intervene and turn the string back to a number (eg using CDbl() ). If you enter a value (or change) a number directly on the sheet, Excel will try and be ‘helpful’ and convert things that look like numbers into numbers (it does the same with dates). – Solution by @DS_London

Comment: It is worth remembering that there is a difference between the value that Excel stores, and the how it is formatted and displayed. Excel (typically) stores values as numbers or strings. Changing the display format of a value does not change its underlying type. Eg there is no underlying Excel type of 'Date' in a spreadsheet: dates are stored as numbers. It is only the formatting that shows the value as a recognizable date. The way to see a value's is to select the cell and hit 'Shift-Ctrl-#'. This removes any formatting of the value.